# How to target parent of button item to remove it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can use

> `$(this).remove();`

to target and delete the 'read' button, but I want to actually target all elements within the div. I presume this has to be done using .parent but I can't seem to get it to work?

```
_.each(Badges, function(item) 
{
    var wrapper = $('<div></div>');
    wrapper.append('<img id="share_button" class="images responsive-image BadgeImgOutline" src="' + item.imageURL + '" />');

    wrapper.append('<div type="button" class="wrapper portfolio-item-thumb one-third btn_badges btn-danger_badges mrs read">' + 'Remove kudosoo' + '</div>' + '<br>' + '<div class="wrapper b_seperater"></div>' + '<br>');

    $('#container').append(wrapper);
    wrapper.children('.read').click(function() 
    {
        item.fetchedObject.set("B_Notify", "Read");
        $(this).remove();

        item.fetchedObject.save(null, 
        {
            success: function(results) 
            {
                console.log("Read");
            },
```

[image]

Comment: $(this).parent().remove(); ???????

Comment: *"...I can't seem to get it to work?"* ***How*** does it not work when you try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change

```
$(this).remove();
```

to

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

Example:

```js
['testing', 'one', 'two', 'three'].forEach(function(item) {
  var wrapper = $('<div></div>');

  wrapper.append('<div type="button" class="wrapper portfolio-item-thumb one-third btn_badges btn-danger_badges mrs read">' + 'Remove ' + item + '</div>' + '<br>' + '<div class="wrapper b_seperater"></div>' + '<br>');

  $('#container').append(wrapper);
  wrapper.children('.read').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```css
#container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-top: 2px;
}
.read {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: I wouldn't hook `click` on each and every item like that. Instead, I'd just use event delegation rooted in the container:

```js
// Handle clicks - handler is only fired if the click
// passed through a `.read` element en route to the
// container
$("#container").on("click", ".read", function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});

// Add items
['testing', 'one', 'two', 'three'].forEach(function(item) {
  var wrapper = $('<div></div>');

  wrapper.append('<div type="button" class="wrapper portfolio-item-thumb one-third btn_badges btn-danger_badges mrs read">' + 'Remove ' + item + '</div>' + '<br>' + '<div class="wrapper b_seperater"></div>' + '<br>');

  $('#container').append(wrapper);
});
```

```css
#container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-top: 2px;
}
.read {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```